# Why does sending array of type A with some elements of subtype B to Firestore force all to A?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

*Note: The environment for this question is in Swift and Xcode 12.5. I cannot confirm that this occurence happens outside out this environment.*

Consider class `A` and subclass `B: A`, where `B` has some property that `A` does not.

```swift
class A {
  var a
  // ...
}

class B: A {
  var b
  // ...
}
```

Suppose I have an array of `A` containing some elements of type `B`.

```swift
var array: [A] = [A(), B(), A()]
```

I put this array in a object that can be sent to Firestore:

```swift
class Model: Codable {
  var x: [A]
}
```

I send this array to Firestore under a document, populating `x` with the value from `array`:

```swift
someReference.setData(from: Model(x: array))
```

In the Firestore console, however, the data is all of type `A`, and property `b` is not present anywhere in the database.

Is this an intended behavior? Why does this occur? Or, did I do something wrong while structuring/sending this data?

Comment: Are you talking about the property b from call B?

Comment: @LucasDahl Yes, when B is initialized with `B()` I assume that `b` is given a value.

Comment: If you are not going to override var a, you do not need it in class B , unless I am missing something. Can you show a picture of the data base in the firestorm console?

Comment: @LucasDahl Whoops, I made a mistake in my code. Var `a` is not meant to be overridden. https://ibb.co/ZV38Qr1 - I have an array of objects containing objects of type `Goal`, yet one of the `Goals` should be of type `SpecialGoal: Goal`. The `SpecialGoal` loses one of its properties when sent to Firestore.

Comment: The property should be the mentioned a that’s overridden, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by uploading each object individually to Firestore, previously downcasting the object if needed:

```swift
class A: Codable {
    var a: String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case a = "a"
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(a, forKey: .a)
    }
}

class B: A {
    var b: String?
}

var array: [A] = [A(), A(), B()]

for item in array {
    if item is B {
        let downcast_item = item as! B
        someReference.setData(from: downcast_item)
    } else if item is A {
        someReference.setData(from: item)
    }
}
```